# How to check the behavior of slope of the differential equation $y'(x) = \arctan[(2-y^2)(x^2+xy)]$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, graphing-functions

Given the Cauchy Problem,

$$ y'(x) = \arctan[(2-y^2)(x^2+xy)] $$ with initial conditions $y(0)=k$

---

I know that there are two horizontal asymptotes at $y=+\sqrt2$ and $y=-\sqrt2 $. Also, the $y'=0$ at $y=-x$. But I cannot understand how the slope increases or decreases between these asymptotes. The below-attached graph indicates when the slope increases (denoted as $+$) and the slope decreases (denoted as $-$). May I know how these signs are evaluated?

[image: Qualitative Graph]

Comment: I think the signs are primarily governed by the $y=-x$ slope. If the $y=-x$ slope is increased, say $y=-1.5x$ slope, then $x^2+xy$ is negative, or in other words derivative is negative because $tan(-x)=-tan(x)$. Similarly, if $y=-x$ slope is decreased, say $y=-0.5x$, then then $x^2+xy$ is positive because $tan(+x) = tan x$. Is this the sufficient reasoning or am I being wrong anywhere?

Comment: Yes, the sign of the derivative will match the sign of $(2-y^2)(x^2+xy)$ because arctan preserves sign.